# Запуск программы с выводом после закрытия моей

Tags: node.js, vb.net, процесс

Хочу сделать программу, которая запускает другую программу (например, `cmd` с командой `ping 8.8.8.8`) с наследованием дескрипторов ввода-вывода. Но при этом моя программа должна завершиться раньше, чем запускаемая (успешно) совершит вывод в унаследованную консоль:

[image: скриншот запуска программы на VB.NET]

На VB.NET это получилось очень легко:

```vb
Module Program
  Sub Main()
    Process.Start(New ProcessStartInfo With {
      .FileName = "cmd",
      .Arguments = "/c ping 8.8.8.8",
      .UseShellExecute = False
    })
  End Sub
End Module
```

Но на nodejs почему-то не получается:

```
require('child_process').spawn("cmd.exe", ["/c", "ping 8.8.8.8"], { 
  // detached: true,
  stdio: 'inherit',
  shell: false,
}).unref();
```

Если не использовать `detached`, то ничего не выводится, а если использовать, то открывается отдельная консоль. Как добиться того же эффекта, что и на VB.NET?

Comment: может быть nodejs и VB используют разные функции WinAPI в итоге для создания процесса, из приведенного листинга видно что в случае с VB явно будет CreateProcess. а в варианте с nodejs возможно ShellExecute который скорее всего не может перенаправить потоки ввода/вывода

Comment: @kandellak, `shell: false` на результат не влияет. Если программа не завершится до вывода запущенной, то вывод в унаследованную консоль работает (при отсутствии `detached: true`).